# Testing jpa ddl types

Tags: java, junit, playframework

I'm trying to run some tests and every time I run play it clears the database. I guess this is due to my **"test.jpa.ddl"** property.

**Current code:**

```
%test.jpa.ddl=create-drop
```

Is it just removing this line to solve the problem? Or do I need to setup another value? (I'm afraid of testing and remove all the data again...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a value of

```
test.jpa.ddl=none
```

That's assuming your JPA provider is doing that.

Alternatively, you could be using DBUnit to do unit tests.  In that case, it will wipe out your data every time they are run.  There really isn't a way around that other than saving your data and loading back up afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your other settings are for your test mode. By default, the database is set up as in memory, so this may be your issue.

Also, are you using Fixtures? If you are not, I would highly recommend using fixtures as it allows you to specify your test data in a YAML file, and load it fresh at the start of every test cycle, which guarantees the consistency of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are using h2 db (it's by default). The simplest way to keep your data is comment this line:

> db=mem

And change it to

> db=fs

If you are using standalone database (like mysql), then you definitely need to go to "jpa.ddl". Change it to "none" as the others say.